# Let $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ be measurable with $\mu(E)<\infty$. Show that the function $\phi(x)=\mu(E\cap(-\infty,x])$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ be measurable with $\mu(E)<\infty$. Show that the function $$\phi(x)=\mu(E\cap(-\infty,x])$$ is continuous.

The definition of a continuous function is given $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $|x-p|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(p)|<\epsilon$.

Proof: Let $p\in E$. Fix $\epsilon=\delta$. So $$|\phi(x)-\phi(p)|=|\mu(E\cap(-\infty,x])-\mu(E\cap(-\infty,p])|$$

Without loss of generality, we can say $x\geq p$. This implies that $(-\infty,p]\subseteq (-\infty,x]$. Thus, 
$$|\phi(x)-\phi(p)|=|\mu(E\cap(p,x])|=\mu(E\cap(p,x])\leq \mu((p,x])=|x-p|<\delta=\epsilon.$$

I am not sure if I am allow to make the assumption of $x\geq p$ or the fact that $|\mu(E\cap(-\infty,x])-\mu(E\cap(-\infty,p])|=|\mu(E\cap(p,x])|$

Comment: Are you sure is not right continuous instead of continuous?

Comment: The problem says just continuous

Comment: If the measure $\mu$, I suppose is a Borel measure, of any point is zero, i.e., $\mu (\{x\})=0$, in this case I think we have continuity of $\phi$ as defined in your statement, in other case is not clear to me.

Comment: Consider $\mu =\delta_0$, i.e., $\delta_0 (A) =1$ if $0\in A$ and zero otherwise, for $A$ any subset of $\mathbb R$. In this case $\phi (x) =1$ if $x\ge 0$ and $\phi(x) =0$ if $x<0$. So, $\phi$ is right continuous but not continuous.

Comment: So I'm completely wrong in thinking

Comment: Is $\mu$ Lebesgue measure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean Lebesgue measure.

$y>x \implies 0\leq \phi(y)-\phi(x)=\mu (\;E\cap (x,y])\leq \mu (\;(x,y]\;)=y-x.$ 
 $y<x \implies 0\leq \phi(x)-\phi(y)=\mu (\;E\cap [y,x))\leq \mu (\;[y,x)\;)=x-y.$

So $|\phi (x)-\phi (y)|\leq |x-y|$.  So $\lim_{y\to x}\phi (y)=\phi (x).$ The function $\phi$ is Lipschitz continuous.

For an arbitrary measure we could have $\{0\}= E$ and $\mu (\{0\})=1$, in which case $\phi$ is not continuous because $\phi (1)=1$ and $\phi (y)=0$ for $y<0.$

Comment: Thank you. This proof seems more connected with the one I was doing above

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\mu =\delta_0$, where $\delta_0$ is the Dirac measure, i.e., $\delta_0 (A) =1$ if $0\in A$ and $\delta_0 (A)=0$ if $0\not\in A$, where $A$ is any subset of $\mathbb R$.

Clearly $\mu (\mathbb R)=1$. For $\mathbb R$ in the definition of $E$, we have that $\phi$ is $\chi_{[0,\infty)}$, i.e., $\phi (x) =1$ if $x\ge 0$ and $\phi(x) =0$ if $x<0$. So, $\phi$ is right continuous but not continuous.

---

Suppose that $\mu$ is a Borel measure such that $\mu (\{x\})=0$ for any $x$ in $\mathbb R$. Fixed $x$ in $\mathbb R$ and choose a sequence such that $x_n\uparrow x$, i.e. $x_n\le x_{n+1}\le x$ and $x_n\to x$. So

$$\bigcup_n (-\infty,x_n]\cap E =(-\infty,x)\cap E,$$

and $\mu((-\infty, x)\cap E) =\lim_n \mu((-\infty,x_n]\cap E)$ (this is a well known result of measure theory, since $(-\infty, x_n]\subset(-\infty, x_{n+1}] $). Thus, $\mu((-\infty, x)\cap E)+\mu(\{x\}\cap E)=\mu((-\infty, x]\cap E)$. So

$$\phi(x) =\lim_n \phi (x_n).$$

From this follows that $\phi$ is left continuous and since the right continuity is always true, the result follows.